# Duda con consulta SQL filtrado por fecha

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una app con PHP, SQL y usando SGBD MySQL y tengo la siguiente duda. Actualmente tengo esta consulta:

```
$sql="SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos_remoto WHERE idarticulo not in (SELECT ean from articulos_csv)";
```

En base a eso saco un array con `ean` que no coinciden entre ambas tablas (el `ean` es la PK, un código de 13 dígitos) y hago una serie de operaciones. La cosa es que ahora quiero filtrar por fecha, pero no sé si a esta consulta le puedo poner también una condicional como fecha. Es decir, algo así:

```
$sql="SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos_remoto WHERE idarticulo not in (SELECT ean from articulos_csv) AND WHERE fecha>20-07-2020";
```

Por ejemplo. Sólo que me hago un lío porque tenía entenddido que a los WHERE no se les puede poner AND y tampoco sé bien qué formato de fecha acepta SQL.
Añadir que la fecha se la metería desde una variable de PHP (que no sé si tiene el mismo formato de fecha que SQL) con lo cual, más bien sería algo así:

```
$sql="SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos_remoto WHERE idarticulo not in (SELECT ean from articulos_csv) AND WHERE fecha>"'$fecha';
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Sí se puede. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos_remoto WHERE idarticulo not in (SELECT ean from articulos_csv) AND fecha>'2020-07-01'
```

Lo que no sé bien es como ponerlo con PHP, pero la consulta SQL ya la he sacado.

Comment: Tu consulta en PHP está bien, sólo tienes que corregir el error de concepto. No es que a los `WHERE` no se les pueda poner `AND`, sino que `WHERE` se pone una sola vez, no por cada condición que era lo que estabas haciendo. La consulta correcta en PHP sería: `$sql="SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos_remoto WHERE idarticulo not in (SELECT ean from articulos_csv) AND fecha>'$fecha'";` Había un error de sintaxis en la cadena `$sql`, pero eso creo que lo tendrás ya visto.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)